# Using django model in django template javascript json error

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, parsing

I want to use django model in template javascript and people say I need to make it into json and then pass it so I made json object from `models.py` and `views.py` like this.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import localdate


class Posts(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    lng = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pick_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    music = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    mood = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True)

    # H E R E #
    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "address": self.address,
            "lat": self.lat,
            "lng": self.lng,
            "name": self.name,
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

views.py

```
import json

def post_list(request):
    posts = Posts.objects.all()
    context = {
        "posts": posts,
        "posts_js": json.dumps([post.to_json() for post in posts]),
    }
    return render(request, "posts/map_marker.html")
```

map_marker.js

```
// this js file is linked to map_marker.html

let posts = JSON.parse("{{ posts_js | escapejs }}");
console.log(posts);
```

I want to see how the posts object looks like but it keeps saying json error

```
JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

It's hard to find a reason as I can't look through how the json object looks like.
I also tried `cls=DjangoJSONEncoder` importing `from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder` but it has the same error.
Any helps would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JsonRespone object, check the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects